# XML document unit testing! .net c#

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, xpath, nodechildren

I've got a problem with XML unit Testing.

Basically the problem is that there are 2 identical tags under same xpath, and I don't really know how exactly I should compare all of the children inside

> ...aperson...
>       .../aperson...

if there is another one identical, but with (different values inside)

Samples are made in list and my guess is i need to make both `<aperson> </aperson>` from XML Document in to list as well, but I'm not too sure about it and don't really have an idea how to do it.

```xml
<Person>
    <apersons>
        <aperson>

            <person_name></person_name>
            <person_code></person_code>
            <institut></institut>
            <post></post>
            <rep_type></rep_type>
            <persreg></persreg
            <state></state> 
            <address/>
        </aperson>

        <aperson>
            <person_name></person_name>
            <person_code></person_code>
            <institut></institut>
            <post></post>
            <rep_type></rep_type>
            <persreg></persreg>
            <state></state>
            <address/>
        </aperson>
    </apersons>
</person>
```

C#

```cs
c.Personas.Add(new Person
            {
                Name = "Elga",
                Code = "-10317",
                Institut = "Valde",
                Post = "loceklis",
                RepType = "1",
                Perseg = "-07-03",
                State = "LV"
            });


            // Person2 
            c.Personas.Add(new Person
            {
                Name = "Elga1",
                Code = "-10317",
                Institut = "Valde",
                Post = "loceklis",
                RepType = "1",
                Perseg = "-07-03",
                State = "LV"
            });
```

CODE: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8DgnhB37)

Comment: not sure what you want but you can select the first person with `/Person/apersons/aperson[1]` and second with `/Person/apersons/aperson[2]`

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish: what are the requirements?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enought but flafoux answered it already! Thanks alot!